# NullPointerException in drools 5.5.0-final when retracting

Tags: nullpointerexception, drools

I´ve got a problem with the following rule:

```
rule "Término sin Traducción"
    salience -100
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        traductor : TraductorDeEventosTratados()
            eventoGenerico : EventoGenerico() from traductor.eventoGenerico
    then
        System.out.println("Evento generico: " + eventoGenerico);
            traductor.setEventoGenerico( null );
            update( traductor );
            retract( eventoGenerico );
end
```

It causes a `NullPointerException` when retracting the "eventoGenerico", as though it doesn't exist in the working memory (it exists actually, and another rule sets the `eventoGenerico` to `traductor` previously):

```
Exception executing consequence for rule "Término sin Traducción" in RULA_PROV.SYSTEM_RULES: [Error: drools.retract( eventoGenerico ): null]
[Near : {... System.out.println("Evento gen ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
        at org.drools.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
        at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1297)
```

However, if I make this little change it works fine (this verifies that the eventoGenerico really exists in the working memory):

```
rule "Término sin Traducción"
    salience -100
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        traductor : TraductorDeEventosTratados()
            eventoGenerico : EventoGenerico()
            eventoGenerico2 : EventoGenerico( this == eventoGenerico ) from traductor.eventoGenerico
    then
        System.out.println("Evento generico: " + eventoGenerico);
            traductor.setEventoGenerico( null );
            update( traductor );
            retract( eventoGenerico );
end
```

It looks like a bug, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace? Are you sure you don't have any TraductorDeEventosTratados with a null eventoGenerico?

Comment: Hi Esteban, eventoGenerico is not null since I write System.out.println("Evento generico: " + eventoGenerico); and the log writes the eventoGenerico properly. Besides, in the second example wouldn´t work if it were null... The full stack trace below.

Comment: Erm ... just after printing the value of eventoGenerico, you're setting it to null. Would I be correct in assuming that it works correctly if you change the order as follows?
    retract(eventoGenerico);
    traductor.setEventoGenerico(null);
    update( traductor );
You're currently setting the eventoGenerico Java object to null, and then attempting to retract it. It's not particularly surprising that when attempting to retract your null fact, a NullPointerException occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Drools 5.5 caused by the usage of mvel dialect. I managed to reproduce your error using this simple test:

Java:

```
Model model = new Model("Model A");
DataSample data = new DataSample(model);
ksession.insert(model);
ksession.insert(data);

ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Drools:

```
rule "Rule 1"
dialect "mvel"
when
    $d: DataSample()
    $m: Model() from $d.model
then
    $d.setModel(null);
    update($d);
    retract($m);
end
```

If you remove the **dialect "mvel"** modifier, the rule works as expected. Recently in Drools' mailing list there were some bug reports regarding mvel. Maybe this is one of them.

Best Regards,

Comment: Thanks Esteban, that was my feeling... I hope a patch with the fix will be released soon

Answer (score 1):

You could retract(traductor), but not eventoGenerico.

The problem is that eventoGenerico is a property of your 'traductor' fact. You can't retract it, because you are not referencing the fact in working memory.

You did insert an EventoGenerico object as a separate fact, but it's only in the second (working) example that you have referenced it and are therefore able to retract it.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your quick response. I understand what you mean, but it turns out weird since the java object (eventoGenerico) is the same in both cases, so when you retract it, it should find the factHandle in the working memory and retract it, am I wrong? In short, in the working example, retract( eventoGenerico ) works and retract( eventoGenerico2 ) does not work, being the same java object in both cases...